# How to do Code Behind for a User Control File

Tags: asp.net

I have a dynamic menu that shows select items based on flags in my database. Currently I have the menu on my .aspx page and the code behind on my .aspx.vb page. I'm adding in alot more pages, so I'm trying to seperate the menu using a User Control. However, I'm not sure how to reference the code behind for the .ascx page.

Current code:

```
<ul>
<li id="form1" runat="server"><a title="a" href="a.aspx" target="_blank">A Form</a></li>
<li id="form2" runat="server"><a title="b" href="b.aspx" target="_blank">B Form</a></li>
</ul>
```

Code Behind:

```
Private Sub Customer_LoadData()
        'DECLARE LOCAL VARIABLES
        Dim objContract As Contract = Nothing
        Dim objContractDL As New ContractDL

        'RETRIEVE THE CUSTOMER'S CONTRACT INFORMATION
        If objContractDL.Read(objContract, zintCustomerID) Then

            Call DisplayCustomer(objContract)
            Call DisplayForms(objContract)

        End If

    End Sub    
Private Sub DisplayForms( _
            ByVal objContract As Contract _
        )

            If (objContract.fieldFedLoansFlag = "0") Then
                authform1.Visible = False           
            Else
                authform1.Visible = True
            End If
End Sub
```

I've never seen a .ascx.vb page before, so i don't think that is the solution.

Comment: `"I've never seen a .ascx.vb page before, so i don't think that is the solution"` - Why not?  That's exactly where one would find the code-behind for a user control.  Did you try?  Is something not working?

Comment: I did try. I used this code at the top of the menu.ascx page.     <%@ Page 
 Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" 
 CodeFile="menu2.ascx.vb" Inherits="menu2" 
%>   But I get an error: The directive 'page' is unknown.

Comment: And in what way did that not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments above you are using the Page Directive and with Custom Controls you should be using the Control Directive

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="menu2.ascx.vb"
Inherits="menu2" %>
```

From the Microsoft site the difference between a user control and a page

> A user controls differs from an ASP.NET Web page in these ways:
>
> - The file name extension for the user control is .ascx.
> - Instead of an @ Page directive, the user control contains an @ Control directive that defines configuration and other properties.
> - User controls cannot run as stand-alone files. Instead, you must add them to ASP.NET pages, as you would any control.
> - The user control does not have html, body, or form elements in it. These elements must be in the hosting page.

Comment: That fixed it. I'm still learning about the differences. I have other problems now trying to convert the code behind page. But I'm researching that issue first to see I can resolve.

Comment: If you added the UserControl in Visual Studio by adding from the list of items that can be added, you should have gotten the ascx.vb file automatically, so I don't understand why this is going wrong, unless you are using notepad or try todo things different.